# Curious "Floating point exception (core dumped)" when linking additional library

Tags: c++, cmake, build

I'm trying to make some basic plots using [matplotlib-cpp](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp). My main function is very basic:

```
#include "matplotlibcpp.h"
namespace plt = matplotlibcpp;
int main() 
{
    plt::plot({1,2,3,4});
    plt::show();
}
```

and my CMakeLists.cpp looks like this:

```
project(basic)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) 

find_package(PythonLibs 3.10 REQUIRED)

include_directories(
    /usr/local/matplotlib-cpp
    ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(basic basic.cpp)
target_link_libraries(basic ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

so I build this (`mkdir build`, `cd build`, `cmake ..`, `cmake --build .`), and it works just as it should and shows me a nice little plot. But now I decide I'd like to also use this [external library from Metavision](https://docs.prophesee.ai/stable/installation/index.html) and change my `CMakeLists.txt` (and nothing else) to this:

```
project(basic)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) 

find_package(MetavisionSDK COMPONENTS core REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs 3.10 REQUIRED)

include_directories(
    include
    ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(basic basic.cpp)
target_link_libraries(basic ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} MetavisionSDK::core)
```

and now I'm getting `Floating point exception (core dumped)`. `GDB` tells me that the issue is in some numpy library:

```
Thread 1 "basic" received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x00007fffd708bb9d in gemm_thread_n () from /home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/../../numpy.libs/libopenblas64_p-r0-2f7c42d4.3.18.so
```

But I am very bewildered by this issue. How can it be that just linking in another library can suddenly change the behaviour of my code so drastically? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Try take a look at stack backtrace: run `bt` command. Pretty sure this is ABI incompatibility. You need to use libraries built with an identical compiler.

Comment: What does "ABI incompatibility" mean? I have already run a `bt` in `gdb`, but I was rather bewildered by the output.